# Static Assert Template inherits from class

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, crtp

How can I guarantee that `T` inherits from `Base<T>`?

So I have

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Base { 
public:
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T*, Base<T>*>::value, "Class must inherit Base as public");
};

class DerivedWithPublic : public Base<DerivedWithPublic> { };

int main() {
    DerivedWithPublic p;
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<DerivedWithPublic*, Base<DerivedWithPublic>*>::value, "Class must inherit Base as public");
}
```

The static_assert in main is true. However the one inside of base is false! So the compiler fails. I want the assertions to be within the class itself? Firstly, i dont understand why one passes and the other one doesn't. Secondly, I need a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is because the definition of a class or a template is not complete until its closing brace, but I am not certain enough to state that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`Base<DerivedWithPublic>` is instantiated at the point where it appears in `DerivedWithPublic`'s list of base, at which time `DerivedWithPublic` is not yet complete type since its declaration hasn't been parsed yet. You can delay assertion until it is completed. One possible solution for this problem is to put the assertion in a member function of `Base` that you know must be instantiated, for example the destructor.

[Live example](https://cppinsights.io/s/fe29a526)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Base { 
public:
    ~Base() {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<T*, Base<T>*>::value, "Class must inherit Base as public");
    }    
};

class DerivedWithPublic : public Base<DerivedWithPublic> { };

int main() {
    
}
```